# JavaScript iterate key & value from json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to iterate the following json:

```
{
"VERSION" : "2006-10-27.a",
"JOBNAME" : "EXEC_",
"JOBHOST" : "Test",
"LSFQUEUE" : "45",
"LSFLIMIT" : "2006-10-27",
"NEWUSER" : "3",
"NEWGROUP" : "2",
"NEWMODUS" : "640"
}
```

Here key is dynamic. I want both key = ? and value = ?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get keys array and use **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to iterate over them.

```js
var data = {
  "VERSION": "2006-10-27.a",
  "JOBNAME": "EXEC_",
  "JOBHOST": "Test",
  "LSFQUEUE": "45",
  "LSFLIMIT": "2006-10-27",
  "NEWUSER": "3",
  "NEWGROUP": "2",
  "NEWMODUS": "640"
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + data[key])
})
```

Comment: Great answer !!!
Is there any way to do it with map where each element has key and value (Something built in) ?
I usually create helper function which does this but I'm looking for something to use ES6,7

Answer (score 46):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for that.

```js
const yourObject = {
  "VERSION": "2006-10-27.a",
  "JOBNAME": "EXEC_",
  "JOBHOST": "Test",
  "LSFQUEUE": "45",
  "LSFLIMIT": "2006-10-27",
  "NEWUSER": "3",
  "NEWGROUP": "2",
  "NEWMODUS": "640"
}
const keys = Object.keys(yourObject);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const key = keys[i];
  console.log(key, yourObject[key]);
}
```

Or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const yourObject = {
  "VERSION": "2006-10-27.a",
  "JOBNAME": "EXEC_",
  "JOBHOST": "Test",
  "LSFQUEUE": "45",
  "LSFLIMIT": "2006-10-27",
  "NEWUSER": "3",
  "NEWGROUP": "2",
  "NEWMODUS": "640"
}
const entries = Object.entries(yourObject);
for (let [key,value] of entries) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```