# Reactjs : Better Managing the Input Box and Displaying Multiple items from a rest response

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display the rest-api response on reactjs front-end.

For instance, my rest-api endpoint is :

```
<http://url/searchquery/<db_name>/<sql_query>
```

a live example would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5002/sqlquery/A123vSearch/SELECT DATE,LABEL_NUMBER,FILENAME FROM FILE_INFO_SEARCH WHERE FILENAME MATCH 'C:/Test_Software/opencv_world320.dll'
```

In the above example, i have two questions:

1) How would i ask user to input two variable values (1 for db_name and 1 for sql_query) ? Should i use two input box or should i use '/' slash separator in one single box, which is easier to maintain?

2) If someone changes the sql_query from `SELECT DATA, LABEL_NUMER` TO `SELECT *` How, would i display all the table list in the webpage?

Here is my current 'SearchQuery.js' file

```
export default class SearchQuery extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            query : "SELECT DATE,LABEL_NUMBER,FILENAME FROM FILE_INFO_SEARCH WHERE FILENAME MATCH 'opencv_world320.dll'",

        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.SearchQuery();
        }


      updateSearch(){
        this.setState({query: this.refs.query.value});
        this.SearchQuery(this.refs.query.value);

       }

       render(){
           var tables = _.map(this.state.tables, (table) => {
        return  <li>{table.FILENAME}</li>; 



        return <div align="center">
            <br/><br/>
            <input ref="query" onChange={(e) => {this.updateSearch();}} type="text" value={this.state.query} />
            <br/><br/>


            <ul>{tables}</ul>

            </div>;
        }

        SearchQuery(query = "SELECT DATE,LABEL_NUMBER,FILENAME FROM FILE_INFO_SEARCH WHERE FILENAME MATCH 'opencv_world320.dll'"){
            var url = `http://127.0.0.1:5002/sqlquery/AvSearch/${query}`;
            Request.get(url).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    tables: response.body.output, 
                    total: response.body.totalResults
            }); 
        });
    }
}
```

The above code works fine if i use the standard Query that i have mentioned in the Live Example but doesn't work, if i use the query as 'SELECT *'

Here is my api-response:

```
   {
        "output": [
            {
                "CLIENT_NAME": "dusii", 
                "FILENAME": "C:/Test_Software/opencv_world320.dll", 
                "FILE_DATE": "2016-12-23 15:56:17", 
                "LABEL_NUMBER": "11", 
                "PERM": "----------", 
                "SIZE": "39.91 MB", 
                "USER": "srt/None"
            }, 
}
```

I know that something needs to be changed to display an array of items in table form, its just that i don't know how to do that...something at this line `<li>{table.FILENAME}</li>`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error..Its just that, if the query changes to SELECT * i don't know how to parse all columns of that table...

Answer (score 0):

1- I recommend using two input fields, simply because those are two information and you would not manage  two information in  one field, it will just increase your time spent try to manage it.

2- You can use a pick list to chose the fields to select.. and in response you theoretically have the columns name as IDs of your json  response.

NB: in the map you did  to map over fields, add a key

NB2: the search action should be bind with a button click, else  on each user input you send requests to the server.. and you are not using any library to manage your side effects, like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to control your global application with flux, and [Redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) for side effects.

The title of your question  does not match your questions, if you can kindly change it

To control your response, you can use the method described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673454/javascript-iterate-key-value-from-json) you can iterate over the `object.keys` to key keys..

Comment: Thanks for #1, for #2 can you give an example or reference to a post? Also, for the side-effects part, again can you refer me or show an example of change or library?

Comment: Of course, i will edit my post to give  you a library, but for the #2, can you  please post an  example of  your response ?

Comment: i just did ...posted the example out of rest-api

Comment: I edited too, i posted a reference for a post that iterates over an object keys, as you exactly need

Comment: I believe it's a really small  project, redux  won't add  a lot of  value to it..

Comment: So, are you saying avoid redux? i want it to be very simple. is there a workaround that exists?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, did you solve your problem ? And  yes, your app is  really simple, it  will be  better  avoiding redux